# How to get rid of bad smell in hiking boots after they have been soaked?

Tags: hiking, boots

My hiking boots got soaked multiple times during our last trip in Scotland. The water got in via my pants, behind my gaiters and on my socks. This happened multiple times on the trip with no opportunity to dry them.

Now back home, they smell like hell. Any tips to get rid of that smell?

The shoes are a pair of [haglofs grym](http://www.haglofs.com/en-US/products/footwear/trekking/men/haglofs_grym_en-us.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to [Outdoors.SE]!  I removed your greeting — no need to greet on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put them in your sink and fill the sink with warm water and <s>possibly some</s> no soap.  Leave them like that overnight, then hang them to dry the next morning.  You won't smell them while they're in the water and in the morning, the smell will be gone (and the water will have an interesting colour).

Comment: Do **not** apply soap to the external surfaces of hiking boots! [source](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/how-to-wash-hiking-boots/4974#4974)

Comment: @Vorac Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I have ever found for getting rid of odors, and it works extremely well, is something called ["OdorXit"](http://www.odorxit.com/) which is based on some enzymes that neutralize odors instead of masking them. I've used it successfully on some nasty things, like animal urine under the floorboards of an apartment I renovated, clothing with foul odors, etc.

so, I would definitely recommend using it. Additionally, when you hang things out in the sunlight to dry, this tends to do a good job with odors too.